# IAppbuilder does not contain a definition for "usefacebookauthentication" in asp.net identity for external login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

I want to activate the external login (facebook) in asp.net mvc5 but i don't know what to do with this error. Please help

[image: Click Here for error photo]

Answer (score 6):

That is because that is an OWIN Extension method for using FacebookAuthenticationMiddleware

**Namespace**:   Owin

**Assembly**:  Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook (in Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/owin.facebookauthenticationextensions(v=vs.113).aspx

Check to make sure a reference exists and that there is a using in the class calling the method

```
using Owin;
```

Comment: You may need to install the NuGet package: `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook`